# I can't read property of an object passed between two android activities by using Parcelable

Tags: android, parcelable

This is the class that implements Parcelable:

```
public class MyUser implements Parcelable{

    private String userName;
    private String password;

    MyUser(String u, String p){
        userName = u;
        password = p;
    }

    private MyUser(Parcel p){
        Log.i("Parcel p", p.readString());

        userName = p.readString();
        password = p.readString();
    }

    // Getters
    String getUserName(){ return userName; }
    String getPassword(){ return password; }

    // Setters
    void setUserName(String u){ userName = u; }
    void setPassword(String p){ password = p; }


    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(userName);
        dest.writeString(password);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyUser> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<MyUser>() {

        @Override
        public MyUser createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new MyUser(source);
        }

        @Override
        public MyUser[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MyUser[0];
        }
    };

}
```

In FirstActivity:

```
   username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);

   Intent secondStep = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
   mu = new MyUser(
                username.getText().toString(),
                password.getText().toString()
   );

   secondStep.putExtra("MyUser", mu);
   Log.i(100 +": "+ mu.getUserName(), mu.getPassword());
   startActivity(secondStep);
```

In SecondActivity:

```
   Intent intent = getIntent();
   Log.i("Second Activity", ": +intent.getExtras().getParcelable("MyUser"));
```

My Log is:

```
I/Second Activity: : com.example.username.sunshine.app.MyUser@1e8329b4
```

wheras I was aspecting to read the username written in the **R.id.username**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object and the property are two different things:

```
    MyUser mu = intent.getExtras().getParcelable("MyUser")
    Log.i("Second Activity", ": +mu.getUserName());
```